# Make client-side (browser) javascript request another website and click a button and retrieve a file?

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I'm a newbie when it comes to javascript, but since I have a local intranet web app at work, which I would like to programmatically retrieve a file from by programming another website on the internet, I was wondering if it was at all possible to make client-side (browser) javascript request another website (on the local intranet) and click a button and retrieve a file ? (the next step is to parse this excel file to json in the browser but that's a separate problem).

I have looked at artoo.js on github but am unsure if this is up to the task of clicking a jquery loaded button on that site in question, and retrieve a file.

The local intranet app lacks an API.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't**. Javascript cannot access (private) local file without an explicit file upload made by the user. For public files (i.e. files on a web server) make sure to check if Cross Origin is set up correctly

Comment: This is a on-the-fly generated excel file on a another server. But I understand there’s security issues with JavaScript regarding “CORS”.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, unless [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) is enabled for those files.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Will read as I understand this is for general security.

Answer (score 0):

**Update :**

> This can be done using **Chrome+Pupeeteer+Nodejs**..
>     Read This post this gives a Full Tutorial How to scrap data from a webpage automatically and more..https://codeburst.io/a-guide-to-automating-scraping-the-web-with-javascript-chrome-puppeteer-node-js-b18efb9e9921.

..

> make client-side (browser) javascript request another website (on the local intranet) ...

this can be achieved without `cross-Origin Resource Sharing` If both website are on same server..as in your case LOCALHOST.

> click a button and retrieve a file?

For this, you need a js runtime for executing another website client-side. then you can apply js scripting on the page and manipulate the Dom or fire an event like a button click.

But this is very complex to do So alternatively directly access the file or make a common API endpoint for both the websites.

Comment: Seems like a long answer for an “absurd” question. I didn’t say the websites were on the same server if that’s what you are thinking of. Thanks for the warm welcome to a newbie’s first question ever here.